# wcf service / java client secureconversation security context

Tags: java, wcf, wsdl, cxf, security-context-token

I need a solution for the following:

There's a .NET WCF WebService with a SOAP1.2 binding and this security policy:
(from wsdl: SecureConversationToken)

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BasicEndpoint_policy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <sp:SymmetricBinding
                    xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:ProtectionToken>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:SecureConversationToken
                                    sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <sp:RequireDerivedKeys />
                                        <sp:BootstrapPolicy>
                                            <wsp:Policy>
                                                <sp:SignedParts>
                                                    <sp:Body />
                                                    <sp:Header Name="To"
                                                        Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                                                    <sp:Header Name="From"
                                                        Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                                                    <sp:Header Name="FaultTo"
                                                        Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                                                    <sp:Header Name="ReplyTo"
                                                        Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                                                    <sp:Header Name="MessageID"
                                                        Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                                                    <sp:Header Name="RelatesTo"
                                                        Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                                                    <sp:Header Name="Action"
                                                        Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                                                </sp:SignedParts>
                                                <sp:EncryptedParts>
                                                    <sp:Body />
                                                </sp:EncryptedParts>
                                                <sp:SymmetricBinding>
                                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                                        <sp:ProtectionToken>
                                                            <wsp:Policy>
                                                                <sp:SpnegoContextToken
                                                                    sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                                                        <sp:RequireDerivedKeys />
                                                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                                                </sp:SpnegoContextToken>
                                                            </wsp:Policy>
                                                        </sp:ProtectionToken>
                                                        <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                                                            <wsp:Policy>
                                                                <sp:Basic256 />
                                                            </wsp:Policy>
                                                        </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                                                        <sp:Layout>
                                                            <wsp:Policy>
                                                                <sp:Strict />
                                                            </wsp:Policy>
                                                        </sp:Layout>
                                                        <sp:IncludeTimestamp />
                                                        <sp:EncryptSignature />
                                                        <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody />
                                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                                </sp:SymmetricBinding>
                                                <sp:Wss11>
                                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                                        <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier />
                                                        <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial />
                                                        <sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint />
                                                        <sp:MustSupportRefEncryptedKey />
                                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                                </sp:Wss11>
                                                <sp:Trust10>
                                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                                        <sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens />
                                                        <sp:RequireClientEntropy />
                                                        <sp:RequireServerEntropy />
                                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                                </sp:Trust10>
                                            </wsp:Policy>
                                        </sp:BootstrapPolicy>
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                </sp:SecureConversationToken>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:ProtectionToken>
                        <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Basic256 />
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <sp:Layout>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Strict />
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:Layout>
                        <sp:IncludeTimestamp />
                        <sp:EncryptSignature />
                        <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody />
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:SymmetricBinding>
                <sp:Wss11 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier />
                        <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial />
                        <sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint />
                        <sp:MustSupportRefEncryptedKey />
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:Wss11>
                <sp:Trust10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens />
                        <sp:RequireClientEntropy />
                        <sp:RequireServerEntropy />
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:Trust10>
                <wsaw:UsingAddressing />
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
```

I have an Apache CXF (wsdl2java) client that makes a request call.
How can I add/negotiate the security context token for the request, if it's at all possible (cxf version 2.5.0)?
I am pretty new to this, so a guide4dummies is what I am looking for ;)

Comment: I'm running into this also.  When I point gsoap 2.8 wsdl2h at it and then compile the generated .h using soapcpp2 it creates two proxies.  One for the service I"m trying to call and on called wstProxy.  Haven't figured out how to use it yet.